# Put long value in JSONArray

Tags: java, numbers, arrays

I am trying to put a long value(milliseconds) in JSONArray like this :

```
         long epoc = 1359231233L;
         long milli = epoc*1000;
         System.out.println(milli);
         JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
         arr.put((Long)epoc*1000);
         System.out.println(arr.toString());
```

The output is :

```
1359231233000
[1.359231233e12]
```

I don't want the exponent value in array , how can i get it to display the actual long value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want the exponent value in array , how can i get it to display the actual long value ?

The form you're seeing *isn't* in the array. It's being created by `toString`. The value actually in the array is a `Long`, not a string.

If you want to get the string form of that number without using exponent notation, I expect you'll have to write your own long-to-string routine (or find one, perhaps in Apache commons or similar).

Note that the exponent form is perfectly acceptable [JSON](http://json.org).

Comment: My jquery Flot graph needs the time in milliseconds and it doesn't seem to accept the exponent value.

Comment: @MohammadAdil: Well *that's* unfortunate. I wonder what JSON parser they're using. Probably worth a bug report.

Comment: @MohammadAdil: Are you *absolutely sure*? The `JSON.parse` built into Chrome, Firefox, and IE9 are all fine with it, as is Crockford's `json_parse`: http://jsbin.com/ajunuh/1 Maybe there's a *different* problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Long.toString()` should give you the number in the format you want.

```
 long epoc = 1359231233L;
 long milli = epoc*1000;
 System.out.println(milli);
 JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
 arr.put(Long.toString((Long)epoc*1000));
 System.out.println(arr.toString());
```

Comment: The only problem with this is : output array has a string now
 `["1359231233000"]`

Comment: @Mohammad Adil Honestly, I'm not sure, could you do some preprocessing on the returned data before passing to flot?

Comment: i can sure do the processing if their is no way to get the array in desired format